# What format to be used for money that does not include $?

Tags: c#, numbers, currency, money-format

Here is my example

[image]

I want to remove `$` but the format still the same? How can I possibly do this?

Here is my code in my `datagridview`

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2";
```

expected output

```
(2,138,870,900.11)
19,921,759.23
..and so on
```

Comment: Can you show how you want it displayed I am not sure I understand correctly what you desire?

Comment: Are you looking for a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8.aspx) like `"#,##0.00"`?

Comment: Then don't use `C` format specifier. It is for currency. Looks line `N2` format is good for you. Take a look at more [`Standard Numeric Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @SonerGönül, yes, but i want to make my negative values to like this ex. (1,000.00)..instead of -1,000.00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still want parenthesis for negatives, try:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,0.00;(#,0.00)";
```

---

Alternatively:

```
var provider = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
provider.NumberFormat.NumberNegativePattern = 0;
dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = provider;
dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N";
```

or:

```
var provider = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
provider.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "";
dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = provider;
dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C";
```

but these solutions depend on your current culture info (which might be a good thing, but we don't know what culture you use, so we might not know which properties you need to alter).

Instead of setting the `FormatProvider` property on each column, you can also do:

```
// change 'provider' clone as before
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = provider;
```

but that will affect all parts of your application (for the relevant thread at least).

Comment: @SHINHAN the solution of sthotakura also works perfect, this is in fact some kind of hackier than the solution using some FormatProvider.

Comment: Another option is to simply use `"N"`, but then you have to clone your `CurrentCulture`, and on its `NumberFormat` set the [`NumberNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbernegativepattern.aspx) to `0`.

Comment: @KingKing It depends on his current `NumberFormatInfo`, see my comment above.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen your comment above is just another option, setting `CurrencySymbol` to empty is another option, it should work in any case

Comment: @KingKing I appended to my answer to give more options.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you simply use `N2` instead?

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

[The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString)

Comment: Yes i tried this but when I encountered negative values I want to make it ex. (1,000.00) like this instead of -1,000.00..

Comment: Negative currency amounts are possible? However, the `C` format specifier does also not replace negative values with `1,000`. Sounds as if you should use the `CellFormatting` event. Have a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter - `Console.WriteLine((-1000m).ToString("C2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` --> `(¤1,000.00)` (with `¤` being the currency symbol, note that there is no `-`)

Comment: When using `"N"` or `"N2"`, the way negatives are formatted depends on `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberNegativePattern`, so the above solution is probably good for _some_ culture infos.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.CurrencySymbol = string.Empty;
dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = nfi;
dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2";
```

I tried the following in a Console App, and it seem to be working:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.CurrencySymbol = string.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(nfi, "{0:C2}", -1234567.89));
```

Answer (score 1):

n2 should give you the same without the $.
If you do not want the thousand separator, you can use f2.